# PUGXMultiuserBundle & FOSUserBundle login with email

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony, sonata-admin, pugxmultiuserbundle

I'd like to allow users to login with theire email as well as username like describe in [FOSUserBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/logging_by_username_or_email.html). It works fine but when using PUGXMultiUserBundle, it does not.

app/config/config.yml:

`providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email
pugx_multi_user:
    users:
        user_one:
            entity:
                class: UserBundle\Entity\Vendor`

As I'm using sonata-admin bundle form to register one of my userType (UserBundle\Entity\Vendor), I put in UserBundle/Controller/VendorAdminController:createAction()

```
        if($form->isSubmitted()){
        $discriminator->setClass('UserBundle\Entity\Vendor');

        $userManager = $this->container->get('pugx_user_manager');

        $userOne = $userManager->createUser();

        $userOne->setUsername($object->getUsername());
        $userOne->setEmail($object->getEmail());
        $userOne->setName($object->getName());
        $userOne->setPlainPassword($object->getPlainPassword());
        $userOne->setEnabled(true);
        ...
        }`
```

At that point, every thing is fine, when I want to login with username but when I tried to login with email, I get the following error:
`Invalid credentials.`